# Polish signs in red hat 7 terminal

Tags: locale, redhat

In polish language we have special letters, for example alt+l = ł, alt + o = ó...

It all works fine in Gnome desktop, but in terminal (gnome-terminal) each time I try polish sign i get "?" (quetion mark).

I have changed /etc/locale.conf to :

```
root ~ # cat /etc/locale.conf  
#LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
```

and restarted shell but it didn't help. Os is Red Hat 7.5 .thanks in advance...

Comment: What's the output of the `locale` command in the terminal? What's the output of the `printf '\xc3\xbf\n'` command?

Comment: locale
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
MyLap ~ $ printf '\xc3\xbf\n'
Ã¿

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was settings in yakuake terminal which I was using:

Manage Current Profile > Advanced > Encoding > UTF-8